# Identifying number sequences with optional punctuation

Tags: regex

I am trying to identify account numbers in different formats using a single regex. The following are the different formats I need to detect:

```
12-34-56-78-9
12-3456-78-9
123-456-789
1-23-45678-9
```

We need to detect "-" inbetween a 9-digit number. But there is no clue where "-" could come. As of now, i am creating regex for individual conditions and detecting it. is there a simple regex to detect the above in a single shot?

Comment: You need to identify which regex dialect you are using. You will tend to get PCRE-compatible answers if you don't specify other requirements. See the [regex tag wiki](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/regex/info) for details and additional guidance.

Answer (score 3):

Here you go, that's a pretty simple pattern:

```
^(?:\d-?){8}\d$
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/eQ3bV0/2)

It simply means: find a digit (`\d`), optionally followed by a hyphen (`-?`), 8 times in a row (`{8}`), then the last digit (`\d`). This prevents a hyphen from being the first or last character, and it also prevents two hyphens in a row.